PHP Curl response ends with a 0
I'm currently working on a solution with an API. I'm trying to make a curl request but for some reason, the response always returns with a 0 at the end. I'm not sure if there's a particular header I'm missing, but the documentation for the API itself only mentions using these particular headers. The code I've got here just needs to get an auth token from the API itself so that I can begin using that for operations with the API. For whatever reason, the API doesn't include an API Key. But that aside, here is my code:
class API_Connection {
    public $auth_token;

    public function __construct() {
        $api_settings = get_option('api_settings');

        $url = 'https://api.example.com/api-token-auth/';
        $data = array(
            'username' => $geek_api_settings['username'],
            'password' => $geek_api_settings['password'],
        );

        // get the token
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        
        $auth_token = $result;

        curl_close($curl);

        return $auth_token;
    }

    public function get_auth_token() {
        return $this->auth_token;
    }
}

When I get my response, which is spat out as a json string, it always includes a 0 at the end of the response. Currently the API is throttling me, so an example of the response I'm getting is:

{"detail":"Request was throttled. Expected available in 86400 seconds.","wait":86400}0.

To include the JS, just for prosperities sake, the JS is the following:
$('#curlAPIToken').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: api_settings.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'curl_auth_token'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    });

Just to clarify, the action curl_auth_token is just a very simple function - instantiate the class and then call get_auth_token() after that.
I've been searching around and can't figure out why the 0 comes at the end. I know I've seen it before and I've solved it before, but I'm more used to React solutions and I can't seem to solve it on this PHP front, and haven't found any threads with a solution that's worked for me. How do I get rid of the 0 at the end of the response? And yes, I've tried rtrim(), that hasn't seemed to work either.

curl_exec returns true or false by default, unless you set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option. It writes the response to the output buffer directly, if you don't - so that's your JSON response you got from the API ending up in the output buffer, and then your $auth_token = $result; results in that variable containing only true or false (and false can get converted to 0, in certain contexts.)

On a side note, you are not supposed to return anything in a constructor.

That makes sense. But when I add that header, I lose all of the response, and I simply get a response of 0. In that case, how can I get the actual output from the API? @CBroe

Didn't you mean $this->auth_token = $result;?

After doing some additional testing and applying some of the changes made in the comments from my post, I've figured that the problem lies in the JS rather than the PHP. When using error_log to get the $result it seems to be outputting fine without the 0 at the end, and any variable that I pull from that response also works without the 0, so from the JS end I've applied the following:
// ...
success: function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  // remove trailing 0
  var token = response.slice(0, -1);
}

This should help with any output I get from the API, but the PHP remains untampered with this solution. Thanks for the pointers!
